# "How to fix 'function call problem' in this question"

Tags: python

> File "/home/shubham/PycharmProjects/LeetCode/AddTwoLinkedList.py", line 5, in  class Solution: File "/home/shubham/PycharmProjects/LeetCode/AddTwoLinkedList.py", line 35, in Solution addTwoNumber(l1, l2) TypeError: addTwoNumber() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l2'

```py
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val=x
        self.next=None
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumber(self,l1,l2):
        head=l3=ListNode(0)
        carry=0

        while l1 or l2 or carry:
            if l1:
                carry+=l1.val
                l1=l1.next
                if l2:
                    carry+=l2.val
                l2=l2.next

                l3.val=carry%10
                carry=carry//10

                if l1 or l2 or carry:
                    l3.next=ListNode(0)
                l3=l3.next
        print(head)
        return head

    l1 = ListNode(2)
    l1 = ListNode(4)
    l1 = ListNode(3)
    l2 = ListNode(5)
    l2 = ListNode(6)
    l2 = ListNode(4)
    addTwoNumber(l1, l2)
```

Comment: File "/home/shubham/PycharmProjects/LeetCode/AddTwoLinkedList.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Solution:
  File "/home/shubham/PycharmProjects/LeetCode/AddTwoLinkedList.py", line 35, in Solution
    addTwoNumber(l1, l2)
TypeError: addTwoNumber() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l2'

Answer (score 2):

I see a few issues with your code.

First of all, Python is whitespace based language.

As a result, your chunk of code

```
l1 = ListNode(2)
l1 = ListNode(4)
l1 = ListNode(3)
l2 = ListNode(5)
l2 = ListNode(6)
l2 = ListNode(4)
addTwoNumber(l1, l2)
```

is actually in the body of your `Solution` class.

This needs to be pulled out to the global scope of the file. To make this post shorter, I've removed the body of your code.

```
class Solution:
    # put your code in here

s = Solution()
l1 = ListNode(2)
l2 = ListNode(6)
answer = s.addTwoNumber(l1, l2)
```

Notice, how I also created an instance of `Solution`. We need to do this because `addTwoNumber` is an instance method of `Solution`

Then you run that file with `python your_filename.py`

You are getting `TypeError: addTwoNumber() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l2'` because Python automatically supplies the `self` variable which references an instance of an object when you invoke an instance method.

However, you have not allowed Python to supply that `self` because it is currently being called like it is a static method so it fills the arguments left to right. Which means, it is passed "self" and "l1" with `l1` and `l2` respectively but your function expects 3 arguments.

Comment: dear as u said ,i done.but i'm not getting output and also there is not showing any error

Comment: this code is already run on LeetCode, but now i want to print it in proper way in IDE ,so can u help me out,if u can???

Answer (score 1):

Function `addTwoNumber` is a member function, so it needs value of `self` to be passed either as `addTwoNumber(selfValue, l1, l2)` or as `selfValue.addTwoNumber(l1, l2)`.

Just replace `selfValue` whith whatever value you want to pass as `self` parameter.